# How to import datapump export file from XE 11g to XE 18c

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-xe, impdp, oracle18c, pluggable-database

I have datapump single schema export generated on 11g XE.
I want to import it to 18c XE.

I'm using command line impdp.

At first, I was getting message:

```
UDI-01017: operation generated ORACLE error 1017
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Later, after some fixing, I moved to error:

```
UDI-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

I haven't found any article that explains all steps I need to do, so, after I found (my) solution, I decided to write this post so others can benefit from it.

It is mandatory to have tns names entry for your pluggable database service.
Typical entry:

```
XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = computer-name)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )
```

Then, when running impdp, you have two options.

If you write auth data inside command line, it has to be in format username/password@xepdb1 (hostname is optional, for those who need it).
If you write auth data at prompt, then first type username@xepdb1, then password.

I was using DATA_PUMP_DIR for dump file (almost). 
Have in mind, there is subdirectory with the name containing GUID of pluggable database in question, one for each such database. So, I put the dump file into specific GUID-named subdirectory.

Then I executed command line like the one below and typed auth data at prompt.

````
impdp DUMPFILE=EXP-SERVICEDATA.DMP LOGFILE=EXP-SERVICEDATA.LOG DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR SCHEMAS='servicedata' CONTENT=ALL STATUS=15
```none

Now import worked as expected.
Let me know if it worked for you.
````

Comment: Why downvote? I have put the solution into another comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (quote from initial post).

It is mandatory to have tns names entry for your pluggable database service. Typical entry:

XEPDB1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = computer-name)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
    )
  )

Then, when running impdp, you have two options.

If you write auth data inside command line, it has to be in format username/password@xepdb1 (hostname is optional, for those who need it).
If you write auth data at prompt, then first type username@xepdb1, then password.

I was using DATA_PUMP_DIR for dump file (almost). Have in mind, there is subdirectory with the name containing GUID of pluggable database in question, one for each such database. So, I put the dump file into specific GUID-named subdirectory.

Then I executed command line like the one below and typed auth data at prompt.
impdp DUMPFILE=EXP-SERVICEDATA.DMP LOGFILE=EXP-SERVICEDATA.LOG DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR SCHEMAS='servicedata' CONTENT=ALL STATUS=15

Now import worked as expected.

Comment: Tnsnames entry should be in server tnsnames file.